# How to check a form is available or not by using its id - jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check weather a form is available or not using jquery.

For example :

**1. I am having a form ID called form1**

**2. I need to check in the page weather the id contains a form or not.**

**3. How can i achieve it using jquery.**

Thanks in advance....

Comment: `if ($('#id-of-form').length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `length` property like this:

```
if ($('#form1').length > 0){
   // form exists
}
else {
   // form does NOT exist
}
```

Docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

look after a form + id

```
if($("form#form1").length > 0) { alert('a form with and id "idname" was found!'); }
```

or:

```
var form = $("#form1");
if(form.length > 0 && form[0].tagName === "FORM")  { alert('a form with and id "idnam" was found!'); }
```

if you want to really check if #form1 is a form.